# Showing that if $f$ and $g$ are continuous at $a$ then $c_1f + c_2g$ is also continuous at $a$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and $(Y, \left|\left|\cdot\right|\right|)$ be a normed space and $f, g: X \to Y$ be continuous at $a \in X$. I want to show with the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition that if $f$ and $g$ are continuous at $a$ then $c_1\cdot f + c_2\cdot g$ is also continuous at $a$ for arbitrary scalar $c_1, c_2$. I have a hunch that using the preimages and open balls might be the easiest way to go. By continuity of $f$ and $g$, we know that there exists such a $\delta_f$ and $\delta_g$ that $\mathcal{B}_{\delta_f}(a) \subset f^{-1}\left[\mathcal{B}_{\epsilon}\left(f(a)\right)\right]$, $\mathcal{B}_{\delta_g}(a) \subset g^{-1}\left[\mathcal{B}_{\epsilon}\left(g(a)\right)\right]$ for arbitrary $\epsilon$.

But after this I can only wave my hands and state that similarly for $c_1f$ and $c_2g$ there exists $c_1\delta_f$ and $c_2\delta_g$ such that $\mathcal{B}_{c_1\delta_f}(a) \subset \left(c_1f\right)^{-1}\left[\mathcal{B}_{\epsilon}\left((c_1f)(a)\right)\right]$, $\mathcal{B}_{c_2\delta_g}(a) \subset \left(c_2g\right)^{-1}\left[\mathcal{B}_{\epsilon}\left((c_2g)(a)\right)\right]$. I do not know how to progress beyond this point, but I suspect that there is some simple trick I just do not know at the moment.

Edit: I just realized that since the metric in the codomain is $d_{Y}(f(x), f(a)) = \left|\left|f(x) - f(x)\right|\right| \leq \left|\left|f(x)\right|\right| + \left|\left|f(a)\right|\right|$, the easiest way to finish the proof is to first choose such deltas for $f$ and $g$ that $d_Y(f(x), f(a)) \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2c_1}$ and $d_Y(g(x), g(a)) \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2c_2}$, and then apply the triangle inequality for $h = c_1f + c_2g$ to derive the desired $< \epsilon$.

In any case, if you happen to know some other way to finish this proof I am more than happy to read it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Edit: you were progressing nicely. I'll go that way.
First choose an $\epsilon >0$, then by the continuity of $f$ and $g$ at $a$, there exist $\delta_1, \delta_2 >0$ such that $\|f(x)-f(a)\| < \frac{\epsilon}{2|c_1|}$ whenever $d_X(x,a)< \delta_1$ and $\|g(x)-g(a)\| < \frac{\epsilon}{2|c_2|} $ whenever $d_X(x,a)< \delta_2$. Let $\delta=\frac{1}{2}\min \{\delta_1, \delta_2\}$,
then for $d_X(x,a)<\delta$,
$\|(c_1f+c_2g)x-(c_1f+c_2g)a\|=\|c_1f(x)+c_2g(x)-c_1f(a)-c_2g(a)\|\leq |c_1| \cdot \|f(x)-f(a)\|+|c_2| \cdot \|g(x)-g(a)\|<\epsilon$.

If one or both of $c_1, c_2$ is/are zero then it's obvious.